# How to enable KeyBinding for DelegateCommand in Prism 4?

Tags: wpf, prism, key-bindings, delegatecommand

I would like to enable a KeyBinding for a DelegateCommand in a Prism4 desktop application.  For example, in my XAML file I have this:

```
<Grid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+A" Command="{Binding Command3}"/>
</Grid.InputBindings>

<StackPanel>
   <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="HitMe" prism:Click.Command="{Binding  Command3}" />
</StackPanel>
```

and in my ViewModel I have this:

```
public DelegateCommand<string> Command3 { get; private set; }

    private void ExecuteCommand3(string commandParameter)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ExecuteCommand3");

    }

    private bool CanExecuteCommand3(string commandParameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

When I press the HitMe button the debug line outputs but pressing CTRL+A has no effect.

I have considered using the CommandReference class from TestMvvmExample2341 but that seems to duplicate the functionality of Prism 4 mechanisms.

Is there a an easy way to have CTRL+A invoke the Command3 in Prism4?

Comment: What version of .NET? 3.0, 3.5, or 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

That's it, maybe your problem is related to the Focus in your view, try this:

At runtime set the focus over the Button and then apply the keystroke. Also take a look at these posts:

[WPF MVVM KeyBinding not being recognized right away and not always working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691501/wpf-mvvm-keybinding-not-being-recognized-right-away-and-not-always-working)

http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-commandreference-and-keybinding.html

Comment: Thanks mascab! That was it.  I added a call to firstButtonName.Focus() within the UserControl_Loaded event so that no tabbing is required.

Comment: Hello Tom, that's great, but if you are planning to use MVVM with Prism maybe setting the focus in the code-behind will break the MVVM pattern. I recommend that you is to use the _FocusManager_, take a look to this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178449/wpf-mvvm-focus-field-on-load)