# Keyboard shortcuts not working until I click a control in the View for MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm having a weird problem.  I binded some keyboard shortcuts like so:

BroadcastView XAML:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Key="F1" Command="{Binding StartRoundClockCmd}"/>
  <KeyBinding Key="F2" Command="{Binding StopRoundClockCmd}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

MainWindow XAML

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Broadcast">
            <view:BroadcastView/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Options">
            <view:OptionsView/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

but the problem is.. when I start the application.. F1 and F2 don't work.. i can click anywhere within the TabItem thinking I just need it to focus the tabitem.. but still nothing.. it's only when I click within a textbox.. or click a button on the View (within the TabItem) first.. THEN the keyboard shortcuts work.

how can I get it so that the keyboard shortcuts will work from application startup using MVVM?

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128898/keybindings-without-any-focus

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Keyboard.Focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focus(v=vs.100).aspx) and [FocusManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) if I were you.
You can set the focus on your usercontrol so it receives the keyboard shortcuts.